# jaxb and xlink - friends or foes?

Tags: xml, rest, jaxb, cxf, xlink

i want to build a rest service via cxf.
this is already done with only two objects "Earthpart" and "Earthquake".
when i call localhost/earthpars i get a xml list of the earthparts with the earthquakes.
but the earthquakeobject with more information {how heavy, how long, etc.} is only available with a xlink to localhost/earthquake/{id}
shortly: In localhost/earthpars is only the xlink to localhost/earthquake/{id}.

now the technical part:
to be honest the request was to use camel-cxf and jaxb to build a REST service. building xlinks with jaxb is possible with namespaces but thats obviously not the way to go! so the question is: is there any info about xlink in connection with jaxb anywhere or is that not the way to go for xlinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an XmlAdapter to convert the child object to an xlink representation.  For more information on XmlAdapter see:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/07/xmladapter-jaxbs-secret-weapon.html

Comment: awesome thanks! i was able to complete this within 30 minutes! so they are friends ^^